# Combinatorics question: How many different ways of colouring three different objects from four different colours?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Say I have three objects, object A, B and C.

If I have four colours, say red, yellow, blue, green, how many different ways are there of painting the objects A B and C?

Is the answer just 4 * 4 * 4 = 64? Or is that too simple.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

The way you formulate the question implies that the objects A, B and C are distinguishable and that several objects can be painted the same color. If this is indeed the case, then you could interpret the objects A, B and C as a "string" of three "places", in which you could put a letter representing the color. In the first place of this string , you can place one of four colors, giving four strings with the other two places still unocupied. For each of these strings, you can put one of four colors in the second place, giving you 4*4 strings and doing the same for the third place, you indeed end up with 4*4*4 strings, representing all possible colorings of the three objects.